# How to make the custom dialog responsive in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am using a bootstrap 2.3.2 modal window and I am trying to accomplish a custom height and width.

In my CSS I have

```
.modal.customcontainer {
    width: 1000px; 
    margin-left:-33%; 
}
```

and this is the modal pop up

```
<div id="Test" class="modal customcontainer fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
       </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
             <img align="middle" title='<%=title %>' src='<%=url %>'>
        </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
           <div class="caption">
                 <p><%=title%></p>
           </div>
      </div>    
  </div>
```

```
</div>
```

Even though the dialog opens as per the dimension, it is not responsive. What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing the media queries.

Comment: You could use a percentage inside of a fixed width.

Comment: I tried percentage also..  I have something like this@media (max-width: 979px) {
 .modal-open.page-overflow .page-container .navbar-fixed-top,
 .modal-open.page-overflow .page-container .navbar-fixed-bottom  {
  overflow-y: visible;
 }
}